# Displaying data on the page from the data gotten from parse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, parse-platform, parse-server

I have offers table and users table on parse server. I did a query for he offers table and it worked great (both console log and html - I had issues with async and the Q.promise helped). Now I'm trying to add two elements that are in the users table. I get it on the console, but not on the page. Here is what I have on the offers.service:

```
    this.getAllOffers = function () {

    var Q = $q.defer();
    console.log('getAllOffers called');

    //all offers filter is selected
    this.allOffersFilter = false;

    var offers = Parse.Object.extend("Offer");
    var exchanges = Parse.Object.extend("Exchanges");
    var users = Parse.Object.extend("User");

    var query = new Parse.Query(offers);
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(users);

    var results = [];

    query.descending("createdAt");
    query.limit(4);

    userQuery.find().then(function(users) {
        for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            foundUsers = users[i];

            query.find().then( function(offers){
            for(i = 0; i < offers.length; i++){
                found = offers[i];
            var result = {};

            result.date = found.get("createdAt");
            result.price = found.get("price");
            result.status = found.get("accepted");
            result.lastName = foundUsers.get("lastName");
            result.companyName = foundUsers.get("companyName");

            console.log(result.companyName);
            console.log(result.price);
        }
    });
    results.push(result);
  }
  Q.resolve(results);
    });
  return Q.promise;
  };
```

Then my HTML:

```
    <!--List of offers-->
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>List of offers</h4>

        <div ng-if="offersList">
            <div ng-repeat="offer in offersList">
                <div class="offer card">
                    <div>{{offer.username}}</div>
                    <div>{{offer.companyName}}</div>
                    <div>{{offer.date}}</div>
                    <div>{{offer.price}}</div>
                    <div>{{offer.status}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="!(offersList)">There are no offers</div>
    </div>
```

Then my component:

```
angular.module('offersPage')
.component('offersPage', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/offers-page/offers-page.template.html',
    controller: function(AuthService, PageService, OffersService, 
$scope) {
        // Functions for offers-page

        // Check if user is logged in and verified on page load
        AuthService.userLoggedin(function(loggedIn, verified) {
            if(!verified) {
                PageService.redirect('login');
            }
        });

        this.$onInit =  function() {
            OffersService.getAllOffers().then(function(offersList) {

            $scope.offersList = offersList;
            });
      }
    }
});
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE !

Comment: Can you show your html? This will let me help you further.

Comment: yes! Sorry, should have done it before. I just added on the question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is offersList in your callback on the $onInit function. Is it empty?

Comment: @Ohjay44, yes, it's empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resolving `$q` before `results` is populated, so, you list is empty.

I don't know about `Parse server`, but if `userQuery.find().then` is `async`, then need to move `Q.resolve(results);` inside it, or probably inside `query.find().then`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do an `ng-if` in angularjs it literally takes out the element and when it puts it in it is as a child scope. To fix this you need to make sure and put `$parent` on any child element inside an `ng-if`. See below. Make sure to use `track by $index` to when you are doing repeats its good practice. Also notice you dont need to `$parent` anything in the repeat since it is referencing `offer`which is defined.

Code:

```
<div ng-if="offersList">
            <div ng-repeat="offer in $parent.offersList track by $index">
                <div class="offer card">
                    <div>{{offer.username}}</div>
                    <div>{{offer.companyName}}</div>
                    <div>{{offer.date}}</div>
                    <div>{{offer.price}}</div>
                    <div>{{offer.status}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Still it's not displaying on the page. I really don't think the issue is on the html, my call back is empty even when doing promises. If I remove the user's query, I get all the offers information on the page, but I need both user's and offers on the page.

Comment: If your offersList is empty then you definitely want to take a look at the query. Above explains the angular side but it sounds like your issue doesnt have to do with your angular code.

Comment: As it is displaying data on the console, I believe the query works. Thanks for helping anyways! =)

Comment: Your query works yes but the point I am making is that the return is not making it to angular if offersList in the callback is empty meaning you are potentially not returning properly.